# How to apply themes on child windows without managed application

Tags: c#, wpf, mfc, themes

I'm using MahApps.Metro to apply themes on my wpf applications. It works without any problem.
But if I create a WPF-Window (DLL) and use it as child window in a third-party application, which is built in MFC (I use WindowInteropHelper to bridge the the MFC and WPF windows), I see no possibility to apply themes on the WPF-window.
Is there any way at all, to apply themes on windows without managed application?
Thank you!

Comment: Are [visual styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773175(v=vs.85).aspx) enabled in your native MFC application.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: Visual Styles apply to native windows and controls. They have no bearing on WPF windows.

Comment: Thank you for your replies.

Comment: I have no control over MFC application.
Maybe it is not possible to only change child-window style, except using window-api's.